# CSS link doesn't work because of MvcConfig class. (Java | Spring)

Tags: java, css, hyperlink

## Problem:

When i annotate MvcConfig class with **@Configuration** **@EnableWebMvc** CSS link stops working.

And i get two **warnings in IDE**:

- No mapping for GET /css/main.css;
- No endpoint GET /css/main.css.

In addition, in the browser console (Google Chrome), the console displays the following error:

- Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

When i open CSS link (http://localhost:8080/css/main.css) in browser i get 404 error page.

---

## Question:

What i need to configure in MvcConfig class so that the css link works?

---

## In my project im using:

- Spring boot;
- Spring security;
- Thymeleaf;
- Maven.

## Code:

CSS link:

`<link th:href="@{/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

MvcConfig class now is empty(the css link doesn't work while I have annotations):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

## What did I try to do:

Im trying to override **addResourceHandlers** method:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```